# Install ffmpeg 0.7.1-5 from debian package

Tags: software-installation, ffmpeg, dpkg

I downloaded this [package for ffmpeg](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/i386/ffmpeg/download).
When I try to install it with command

`sudo dpkg -i ffmpeg_0.7.1-5_i386.deb`

it writes this error message:

```
Unpacking ffmpeg (from ffmpeg_0.7.1-5_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing ffmpeg_0.7.1-5_i386.deb (--install):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-ipod640.ffpreset', which is also in package libavcodec-extra-52 4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing: ffmpeg_0.7.1-5_i386.deb
```

Could you help me with the installation of this particular version (0.7.1-5) for Ubuntu 10.04?

EDIT: after command
`sudo apt-get remove libavcodec52 libavcodec-extra-52`

[new output](http://pastebin.com/VVuKn8iQ)

Should I go manually now step by step and install the dependencies (and possibly their dependencies) or is there some trick?

Comment: Why do you downloaded the package and don't you use the package available in repositories?

Comment: I need this version of the package.

Comment: Did you try letting apt-get install exactly this version before? That is: apt-get install ffmpeg=0.7.1-5 ? After that, you'll have the right dependencies installed and can try to manual install your version with dpkg.

Comment: @thiton Yes but this writes `E: Version '0.7.1-5' for 'ffmpeg' was not found`

Comment: OK. Which version /do/ you have available? "apt-cache show ffmpeg | grep ^Version" should show you.

Comment: @thiton The output is [this](http://pastebin.com/ygK1VzNw)

Comment: Oh, well. Just missed the epoch (4:) on the version number. Then install apt-get install ffmpeg=4:0.7.1-5 and be happy :-).

Comment: @thiton I tried it with [this](http://pastebin.com/V1nPCEf6) output, but believe we're closer to the solution.

Comment: This is what happens when you try to install a debian library package deb in an ubuntu system. Seriously, don't unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Always clearly state in the question which distribution you are using. It seems likely this is either Debian or Ubuntu. If so, please also state the version, i.e. Debian squeeze. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Mixing binary packages from debian and ubuntu repositories is a very bad idea. However, if you're absolutely sure you need *that* specific version, a possible solution is to download the debian package *source*, then set up `build-essential` on your system and build the package locally so it'll match the proper dependencies.

Add the line

```
deb-src http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
```

to your `sources.lst` file and then enter

```
apt-get update
apt-get build-dep ffmpeg
apt-get source ffmpeg
```

This will attempt to download all the packages needed to build the `ffmpeg` package (mostly libwhatever-dev plus a working compiler) and then download and prepare the source package for ffmpeg in the current directory. I recommend you create and `cd` to `/usr/src/ffmpeg` before taking this step.

You will now have the following files and directories under your current dir:

```
ffmpeg-debian-0.whatever/
ffmpeg-debian_0.whatever-something.diff.gz
ffmpeg-debian_0.whatever-something.dsc
ffmpeg-debian_0.whatever.orig.tar.gz
```

Fairly straightforward: The `orig.tar.gz` is the original source code tarball; the `-something.diff.gz` is a diff applied by debian package maintainers to provide all the debian build scripts, while ffmpeg-debian-0.whatever/ is the unpacked and patched source directory.

`cd` into the source directory and run the command `debuild -us -uc -b`, then fetch a soda refill while your system compiles and builds the package, using your currently existing library versions to determine its dependencies.

Once that finishes, `dpkg -i` the resultant .deb, and enjoy.

Comment: I'm trying to download the source and I'm looking [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=ffmpeg) but can't find the right version.

Comment: What means `setup build-essential`?

Comment: `apt-get build-dep ffmpeg` should take care of that as well; `build-essential` is the  name of the metapackage that depends on all the basic tools debian needs to build packages. Hence, 'build-essential' which can be installed by typing `apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: I tried it but with [this](http://pastebin.com/VTDekmuC) result. What should it take care of?

Comment: After adding the line to the `sources.list` and `apt-get update` there was an error at the end, something with `GPG public key`. And [this](http://pastebin.com/S0TbdjGS) is the new output.

Comment: @xralf When `apt-get build-dep ffmpeg` installs nothing, and shows no error (like in your first output) it means that everything is fine (all the dependencies are already installed). In your second output you are missing the `libva-dev`. The output of your `apt-get update` would also be helpful, but maybe you just need the key for the debian repository: [How to find a key](http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_to_find_a_key).

Comment: @captaincomic [Here](http://pastebin.com/HcW0F3ng) is the error output of `apt-get update`. Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable of GPG.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your installed distribution packages the ffmpeg software suite differently than the distributor you got the ffmpeg package from. The root cause is in the third line; libavcodec-extra-52 has already installed the /usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-ipod640.ffpreset file, and dpkg will not overwrite files from one package with files from another package.

This might have to do with some dependencies - on my Wheezy, ffmpeg 4:0.7.1-5 replaces libavcodec-extra-53 (<< 4:0.6~) and depends on libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.1), so an upgrade to your libavcodec-extra-53 is probably necessary.

You have two options:

1. Dirty hack: Deinstall Ubuntu's libavcodec-extra-52 package, and maybe other components of ffmpeg: apt-get remove libavcodec-extra-52
2. Better: Use Ubuntu's version of ffmpeg: apt-get install ffmpeg

Comment: Thank you. Dirty hack didn't help. See question edit.

Comment: You have to install the new dependencies. As they are not on Ubuntu's repo, you can either: (a) add Debian Wheezy's repo, or (b) download all the dependencies and `dpkg -i` all of them in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to manually download some ffmpeg .deb package (btw, where did you get it from?).

Just install it via the distribution's package manager, e.g.:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

The package you have used conflicts with an already installed package and perhaps has other issues. A package manager like apt-get is able to detect/diagnose and (help to) resolve conflicts.

Comment: I need to install this particular version. See question edit.

Comment: With ubuntu 14.04 this does NOT work.  ffmpeg is not found

Comment: @Mark0978, it seems that Ubuntu has [removed the package `ffmpeg` after Precise (12.04)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ffmpeg) ... - and [re-added it in Ubuntu Vivid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ffmpeg) ...

Comment: Found out that in 14.04, the name of the package is avconv, but it is the same as ffmpeg.